# Kibana Dashboard: Aggregation on Partial Message Match

Tags: kibana, message, aggregation, matching, partial

I'm working on a service that allows users to complete and submit several forms. After each form is submitted a message is logged like:

```
Form submitted Form-001 with draftId (unique Id) and submissionRef (unique ref)
```

I want to aggregate (and count) and visualise how many of each form (based on form name `Form-xxx`) is submitted.

I'm fairly new to kibana dashboards. So, all suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to achieve this. I'm posting it here for the purpose of closure and future references:

The way to do this is with a **scripted field** in *Kibana*. A scripted field can read messages and aggregate them as required. Kibana accepts scripted fields in 2 different languages: *Lucene expressions* and *Painless*.

My solution is written in *painless*:

```
def msg = doc['message.raw'].value;
if(msg != null){ 
    int flagIndex = msg.indexOf('Form submitted');
    if(flagIndex>0){ 
        int toIndex = msg.indexOf(' with draftId');
        return msg.substring(flagIndex+14,toIndex);
    }
}
return "";
```